# variance of number of steps in markov chain (rook move to top right)

Tags: markov-chains

I encountered this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996452/expected-number-of-turns-for-a-rook-to-move-to-top-right-most-corner) while studying Markov chains and I want to calculate the variance of the problem, i.e. variance of number of steps that a random walker rook make to reach from down-left square of a chess board to the top-right square for the fist time.

Update: I found the answer in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).

$$
N = (\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
   6/7 & 1/7 \\
   1/2 & 3/7 \\
  \end{bmatrix})^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
   56 & 14 \\
   49 & 14 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
Which 56+14=70 is the expected number of visits to states 0 and 1 before trapping, starting from state 0. Now for variance:

$$
t=\begin{bmatrix}
   56 & 14 \\
   49 & 14 \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   70 \\
   63 \\
  \end{bmatrix} \\
(2\begin{bmatrix}
   56 & 14 \\
   49 & 14 \\
  \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix})\begin{bmatrix}
   70 \\
   63 \\
  \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
   4900 \\
   3969 \\
  \end{bmatrix}=14\begin{bmatrix}
   331 \\
   328 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Did you try to use the approach explained for the mean in the other answer?

Comment: I really liked to use a more intuitive approach like the other answer and I tried to compute $E[x^2]$ but I couldn't formulate it that way. I have no clear mind on how to relate $x^2$ to number of steps, x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique used to solve the other question shows that the generating function of the number of steps $T$ is such that $$E((1-s)^T)=\frac{(1-s)^2}{1+68s+29s^2},$$ from which the expansion of the RHS up to order $s^2$ yields $E(T)=70$ and $E(T^2)=9534$, hence $$\mathrm{var}(T)=4634.$$

Comment: Where can I find a good resource to study more this approach? --thanks